# QlikView aggr more than one value excluded in list box

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, set-analysis, qlik-expression

I have a list box that is powered by an expression to hide 1 value.

```
=aggr(only({<[name]-={John}>}[name]),[name])
```

But i want to add a second name to this. I have tried...

```
=aggr(only({<[name]-={John, Alan}>}[name]),[name])
```

And

```
=aggr(only({<[name]-={John}, {Alan}>}[name]),[name])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes are required to indicate explicit values:

```
=aggr(only({<[name]-={'John', 'Alan'}>}[name]),[name])
```